# How to change value of a static field using BCEL?

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation, bcel

I want to reset a static field using BCEL, for instance

```
private static final int myValue = 1;
```

to `myValue = 2`. Using another bytecode library such as ASM is not possible.

Comment: Look up the ConstantValue attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in my question: [Injecting code in an existing method using BCEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119702/injecting-code-in-an-existing-method-using-bcel) used to edit a static array. I however later changed it to edit a local variable.
The code to edit a static variable was something like this:

```
InstructionList il = new InstructionList();
InstructionFactory f = new InstructionFactory(constantPoolGen);
il.append(f.createGetStatic("MyClassName","MyVariableName",Type.INT));
il.append(new PUSH(contantPoolGen, 2));
il.append(new ISTORE());
```

The InstructionList I used got injected in a method so i'm not sure if that works for you..